# How to fix java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzbq

Tags: android, firebase, react-native

I'm having NoClassDefFoundException issue on my react-native project (on iOS it works properly) that causes my app to crash on launch. 
The project was going well, and I don't mind to have changed anything that could affect my build.gradle.

Anyway this is the full stacktrace:

```
Process: com.managerapp, PID: 19695
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzbq;
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6391)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5938)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5853)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbq" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.managerapp-_FOS3p5iYciVleWS2bBgrQ==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.managerapp-_FOS3p5iYciVleWS2bBgrQ==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.managerapp-_FOS3p5iYciVleWS2bBgrQ==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.managerapp-_FOS3p5iYciVleWS2bBgrQ==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.managerapp-_FOS3p5iYciVleWS2bBgrQ==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.managerapp-_FOS3p5iYciVleWS2bBgrQ==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.managerapp-_FOS3p5iYciVleWS2bBgrQ==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.managerapp-_FOS3p5iYciVleWS2bBgrQ==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.managerapp-_FOS3p5iYciVleWS2bBgrQ==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.managerapp-_FOS3p5iYciVleWS2bBgrQ==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.managerapp-_FOS3p5iYciVleWS2bBgrQ==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.managerapp-_FOS3p5iYciVleWS2bBgrQ==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.managerapp-_FOS3p5iYciVleWS2bBgrQ==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.managerapp-_FOS3p5iYciVleWS2bBgrQ==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.managerapp-_FOS3p5iYciVleWS2bBgrQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.managerapp-_FOS3p5iYciVleWS2bBgrQ==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.managerapp-_FOS3p5iYciVleWS2bBgrQ==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.managerapp-_FOS3p5iYciVleWS2bBgrQ==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.managerapp-_FOS3p5iYciVleWS2bBgrQ==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.managerapp-_FOS3p5iYciVleWS2bBgrQ==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.managerapp-_FOS3p5iYciVleWS2bBgrQ==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.managerapp-_FOS3p5iYciVleWS2bBgrQ==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.managerapp-_FOS3p5iYciVleWS2bBgrQ==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.managerapp-_FOS3p5iYciVleWS2bBgrQ==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.managerapp-_FOS3p5iYciVleWS2bBgrQ==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.managerapp-_FOS3p5iYciVleWS2bBgrQ==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.managerapp-_FOS3p5iYciVleWS2bBgrQ==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source:2) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6391) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5938) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5853) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/com.managerapp-_FOS3p5iYciVleWS2bBgrQ==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:354)
05-01 15:02:01.251 19695-19695/com.managerapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:101)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:75)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:394)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:354)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:164)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:74)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:74)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:40)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:727)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:810)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1032)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2345)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5749)
                ... 8 more
```

The following are my build.gradle dependencies:

builde.gradle

```
dependencies {
    def DEFAULT_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION    = '15.0.1'
    def googlePlayServicesVersion = rootProject.hasProperty('googlePlayServicesVersion')  ? rootProject.googlePlayServicesVersion : DEFAULT_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION

    compile project(':tipsi-stripe')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    compile project(':react-native-camera')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1"}

The following are the build.gradle of project I reference in my app:
```

react-native-camera

```
dependencies {
  compileOnly 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
  compileOnly 'com.facebook.infer.annotation:infer-annotation:+'
  implementation "com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0"
  implementation "com.drewnoakes:metadata-extractor:2.9.1"
  implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:${safeExtGet('googlePlayServicesVersion', '15.0.1')}"
  implementation "com.android.support:exifinterface:${safeExtGet('supportLibVersion', '27.1.0')}"
  implementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:${safeExtGet('supportLibVersion', '27.1.0')}"
  implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:${safeExtGet('supportLibVersion', '27.1.0')}"
}
```

tsipi-stripe

```
dependencies {
  def firebaseVersion = project.hasProperty('firebaseVersion') ? project.firebaseVersion : DEFAULT_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_VERSION
  def googlePlayServicesVersion = rootProject.hasProperty('googlePlayServicesVersion')  ? rootProject.googlePlayServicesVersion : DEFAULT_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION

  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
  compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:15.0.1"
  compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0"
  compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:8.1.0'
  compile 'com.github.tipsi:CreditCardEntry:1.5.0'
}
```

Any suggestions on how to solve the problem?

Thank you

Comment: What is the version of firebase core?

Comment: Sorry man, didn't see it was missing. 
The version is: 11.8.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0"
```

into this:

```
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8"
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. 

May you explain me why this problem was happening, thus I'll be able to solve it on my own.

Comment: its because the google service version 15.0.1 is not compatible with firebase version 11.8.0, thus the best thing is to update firebase to the latest version, to solve your problem, you can the latest versions here: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android